# What is the word for a structure that covers the part of the house that is lower than the top?

Tags: word-request, nouns

Looking at the definition of *roof*, I read that it is the structure that covers the top of a building.

[image: screenshot]

Suppose that the house shown in the picture didn't have a porch and the garage was extending more outside the house. What word should I use for the (structure covering the) top of the garage? Could I use *roof*, or should I use a different word?

Comment: kiam, interesting! Could you add the link to that picture; on the top-left corner one cannot read what the name of the window of the lucernario is. Thank you.

Comment: It's _dormer window_; see [this picture](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/media/oald8/fullsize/h/hou/house/house_labels_comp.jpg).

Comment: Incidentally they've misspelled *door **knocker***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's still a roof.  You might qualify it and say the *garage roof* or *the roof over the garage* if you want to be specific.